# Accessing a java applet from another directory

Tags: html, applet

I have a apple named "WelcomeApplet" in the following directory:

C:\project\applets\WelcomeApplet.class

And I have a html file here:
C:\project\html\index.html

Now I am trying to access that applet in my code using this tag:

```
<applet CODE="../applets/WelcomeApplet.class" WIDTH="250" HEIGHT="150"></applet>
```

But this does not work! I copyed the applet to same fodler as my html file is and just pointed in CODE tag the name of the file then it worked. Am I providing wrong relative path or the CODE tag only should have the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<applet 
    CODEBASE="../applets/"
    CODE="WelcomeApplet" 
    WIDTH="250" 
    HEIGHT="150">
</applet>
```

The code attribute should be the fully qualified name of the class, i.e. `WelcomeApplet` not `WelcomeApplet.class`.  It is the codebase that specifies where to find the 'root' of the class file location.